# Android Studio interface issue

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, interface

[image: screenshot of android studio]

How can i solve this problem where the interface jumps all over the place?
This happens on Android Studio 1.5.1 (based on IntelliJ), but not on Java IntelliJ IDEA, which is weird.

**Update:**
It doesn't happen continuously, usually after a few minutes in the program.
A full reinstall and restoring default layout is not solving the problem.
However when resizing the window or when dragging the window outside the visible area of the screen, the layout goes back to normal and mostly when the mouse is moved the same issue appears again.

**Update 2:**
Since one of my 2 boot SSD's (in RAID0) gave up on life, I was forced to reinstall Windows and so lost all the programs on the C drive... On this new Windows install the interface issue with Android Studio is gone, so the problem was probably a wrong config file or a problem with Java.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can reinstall it.Also you can click shift+F12 first.